# Discreteness and gap in spectrum - is it the same?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Discreteness is attributed to discontinuous evolution of eigenvalues on the spectrum of an operator. A spectral gap, is the distance between two disjoint points on the spectrum. However, as this gap can describe an interval where there are no solutions, it does not guarantee that the following eigenvalues to the right are not continuous and not discrete. Is the existence of a gap therefore sufficient for guaranteeing discreteness of the spectrum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a finite, compactly-supported Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then the multiplication operator $M : L^2_{\mu}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2_{\mu}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$
           (Mf)(x)=xf(x)
$$
is bounded and has spectrum $\sigma(M)$ equal to the support of the measure $\mu$. Every atom of $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ of multiplicity $1$. The support of the absolutely continuous part of $\mu$ is the absolutely continuous spectrum of $M$. Etc. So it is not difficult to construct self-adjoint operators with specific types of spectra in specific places on the real line. A gap in the spectrum does not have to correspond to discrete spectrum; a gap can occur without any discrete spectrum.

Comment: Disintegrating by parts! What a phenomenal nickname. Thanks for the help here.

Comment: @Luthier : I think you're the first person who commented that they like my nickname. Believe it or not, I heard an old acquaintance talk about how something had disintegrated by parts. They knew nothing about Calculus, and they thought it was very strange that I laughed so hard about what they said.

Comment: It is so fenomenal , and also the location where you live "Over the Hill", that I had to send it to the bass-player of the French band "Skip the Use", who also enjoyed reading your profile with the skeleton and seeing this nickname. Do you have an email address, because I have a paper I would like to publish, which needs a coauthor - in precisely this field. My address you can find in my profile, by visiting the website.

Comment: Not to mention: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQFykrCo6yQ

Comment: @Luthier : I forgot to come back to your comment. Thank you very much for asking about including me on your paper. I am happy to answer any questions you have in this forum that I can answer, but that's about all I can do to help. I'm just a hobbyist. If you want the advice of experts in the field, you should post on mathoverflow.net . The Mathematicians there know more in a drunken stupor than I'll ever know. :)

Comment: Thanks DISINTEGRATING BY PARTS, just send me a mail if you change your mind and want to have a  look at that manuscript, you may find it more easy to work on than you think!

Answer (score 3):

The existence of a spectral gap does not imply that the spectrum is discrete. Example from physics: Most Hamiltonians in quantum field theory have a spectral gap but their spectrum is not discrete, e.g. the spectrum of the free Dirac Hamiltonian of mass $m>0$ is $(-\infty,-m] \cup [m,\infty)$.